# How to get all the rows that have multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT *
FROM Service
WHERE cusId='$cusId'
  AND serviceType IN (1,2)
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 2
```

I want to have last records of services which have serviceType of 1 and 2, when I use this script with IN query, I get 2 rows of services which has serviceType of 1, but I want to have two records, which have 1 and 2 as serviceTypes, sorry for my english

Comment: Still struggling? If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you've not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you've not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(select * from Service 
where cusId='$cusId' 
and serviceType = 1 
order by date desc limit 1)

UNION

(select * from Service 
where cusId='$cusId' 
and serviceType = 2 
order by date desc limit 1)
```

Comment: @user3767986 updated answer, try it with parenthesis

Comment: @user3767986 it depends on which columns you're selecting, you might be able to use `select distinct ... limit 2`, but this is probably the clearest way to do it

Answer (score 0):

can you try union ?

```
SELECT top 1 * FROM Service where cusId='$cusId' and serviceType = 1 order by date DESC
UNION
SELECT top 1 * FROM Service where cusId='$cusId' and serviceType = 2 order by date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id,MAX(date) FROM Service 
where cusId='$cusId' 
and serviceType = 1 
 limit 1

UNION All

SELECT id,MAX(date) FROM Service 
where cusId='$cusId' 
and serviceType = 2 
limit 1
```